# Probing gas giant planets by descending through a cyclones's "eye"?

Tags: probe, planetary-science, interplanetary, gas-giant

On Earth cyclones have regions of calm weather commonly known as eyes. They appear to create tunnels spreading from the top of the atmosphere down to the sea level. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(cyclone)) mentions their presence in other planets as well.

> NASA reported in November 2006 that the Cassini spacecraft observed a
>   "hurricane-like" storm locked to the south pole of Saturn with a
>   clearly defined eyewall. The observation was particularly notable as
>   eyewall clouds had not previously been seen on any planet other than
>   Earth (including a failure to observe an eyewall in the Great Red Spot
>   of Jupiter by the Galileo spacecraft). In 2007, very large vortices on
>   both poles of Venus were observed by the Venus Express mission of the
>   European Space Agency to have a dipole eye structure.

Atmosphere probes don't seem to be able to reach very deep. Contact with [Galileo probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Probe) ended after around 160 km and [Saturn Atmospheric Probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_Atmospheric_Entry_Probe) is expected to survive up to 250 km. Could we reach even deeper if we travel through an eye of a gas giant vortex? Is targeting these viable?

Comment: Nope. The time of loss of orbit is a very strong function of atmospheric density / or pressure for a given temperature. And cyclonic vortices have maybe  1% pressure difference w.r.t their surrounding medium. This compares to the exponential increase of pressure with height. So no chance there.

Comment: cool question! I've adjusted the title slightly, can you double check that it's correct? thanks!